# Git branching model - managing a Deploy/Integration branch in a non-sequential test and a release setup

Tags: git, github, workflow

We are broadly adopting a git branching model based on [nvie.com's suggestion](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

What we can't figure out yet is how to manage the Deploy (aka Integration) branch with regards to feature testing for multiple versions. Even though Nvie's model decouples feature development from the release runway, it seems to assume a queued runway for development, test and release of features.

If we want to start testing early a 'big' feature due in two months (2.0) alongside code we'll ship in a maintenance release much sooner (1.1), what are your suggestions on how we manage that?

I thought about merging all of the Feature/FeatureName branches individually into the Deploy branch and then merging them all again individually into a Release/1.x branch, rather than merging Deploy into Release/1.x which assumes everything you're currently integration testing is going to ship out 'next'.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Stumbled about same issues. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really, but we decided to modify things. Rather than merging Features into Develop and then into a Release branch, we're simply going to create new pull requests from Features to Release when release time comes. This means extra leg work; i.e. our devs create a pull request to Develop and then come release time to Release, but it gives us greater flexibility.